# SSRS Report only generating 1 row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a tablix as below: 
[image]

When I run the dataset query in SQL Server it returns two results however when I run preview on the report it only returns 1. I have a group on FormData where FormData is located.

Comment: have you delete detail section from group section ?

Comment: Or you may be Grouping on a field that has the same value for the field on both records. It may help to post another pic of your table after you click in a cell so the table's row and column blocks appear